# How to get rid of cross join here?

Tags: linq-to-sql

i've got the code that performs slowly, because is transformed to weird SQL:

```
        // Create LINQ query for retrieving objects on which user has permissions to perform supplied action
        var result =

            // Select objects from supplied queryable
            from secureObject in source

            // Create some shorthands for code readablility
            let ownerId = secureObject.AccessControl.OwnerId
            let groupOwner = secureObject.AccessControl.GroupOwner
            let permissions = secureObject.AccessControl.Permissions
            let objectStatus = secureObject.AccessControl.Status

            // Filter out actions that do not apply to this object source
            from ia in this.ImplementedActions
                .Where(ia =>
                    ia.ObjectType == objectType &&
                    ia.ActionType == actionType &&
                    ((ia.Statuses == Status.None) || ((ia.Statuses & objectStatus) != 0))
                )

            // Get action entry for supplied action
            from ac in this.SecureActions.Where(ac => ac.Type == actionType && secureObject != null)

            // Get user matching current principal id
            from u in this.Users.Where(user => user.Name.Equals(userName))

            // Create left outer join for Privileges
            from pr in this.Privileges.Where(pr =>
                pr.ObjectType == objectType
                && pr.Action == actionType
                && (
                    pr.Type == PrivilegeType.Global
                    || (pr.Type == PrivilegeType.Object && pr.RelatedObjectId == secureObject.SecureId)
                    || (pr.Role == RoleType.Self && u.SecureId == secureObject.SecureId && objectType == typeof(User).Name)
                )
            ).DefaultIfEmpty()

            where
                // The action must apply to objects
                ac.AppliesToObject == true
                //ac.AppliesToObject == true

                && (
                // Administrators are always allowed to do everything
                    ((u.Groups & Groups.Administrators) == Groups.Administrators)

                    // Read permissions in the bit field 
                    || (actionType == ActionType.Read && (

                        // The OtherRead access permission bit is on
                        ((permissions & AccessPermissions.OtherRead) != 0)

                        // The OwnerRead access permission bit is on, and the member is the owner
                        || ((permissions & AccessPermissions.OwnerRead) != 0 && ownerId == u.SecureId)

                        // The GroupRead permission bit is on, and the member is in the group
                        || ((permissions & AccessPermissions.GroupRead) != 0 && (groupOwner & u.Groups) != 0))
                    )

                    // Write permissions in the bit field                        
                    || (actionType == ActionType.Write && (

                        // The OtherWrite access permission bit is on
                        ((permissions & AccessPermissions.OtherWrite) != 0)

                        // The OwnerWrite acccess permission bit is on, and the member is the owner
                        || ((permissions & AccessPermissions.OwnerWrite) != 0 && ownerId == u.SecureId)

                        // The GroupWrite permission bit is on, and the member is in the group
                        || ((permissions & AccessPermissions.GroupWrite) != 0 && (groupOwner & u.Groups) != 0))
                    )


                    // Delete permissions in the bit field       
                    || (actionType == ActionType.Delete && (

                        // The OtherDelete access permission bit is on
                        ((permissions & AccessPermissions.OtherDelete) != 0)

                        // The OwnerDelete access permission bit is on, and the member is the owner
                        || ((permissions & AccessPermissions.OwnerDelete) != 0 && ownerId == u.SecureId)

                        // The GroupDelete access permission bit is on, and the member is in the group
                        || ((permissions & AccessPermissions.GroupDelete) != 0 && (groupOwner & u.Groups) != 0))
                    )

                    // User privileges
                    || (pr.Role == RoleType.User && pr.Who == u.SecureId)

                    // Owner privileges
                    || (pr.Role == RoleType.Owner && ownerId == u.SecureId)

                    // OwnerGroups privileges
                    || (pr.Role == RoleType.OwnerGroup && ((groupOwner & u.Groups) != 0))

                    // Group privileges
                    || (pr.Role == RoleType.Group && ((pr.Who & (int)u.Groups) == pr.Who))
                )

                //self privileges
                || (pr.Role == RoleType.Self)

            select secureObject;
```

Here, ImplementedActions and Privileges are transformed to INNER / LEFT JOINs correspondingly, but SecureActions and Users are just CROSS JOINed (?!)

I'm suprised, because it's seen from the condition, that there should be only ONE user selected, for instance, so I expected something like:

```
INNER JOIN "XXX"."USER" "ExtentY" ON ("ExtentY"."USER_NAME" = :p__linq__Z)
```

instead of

```
CROSS JOIN "XXX"."USER"
```

Could you please tell, what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous objects saved me (however, performance is still not good, but it's already a question to DB admins, since they say Oracle plan is not optimal):

```
            // Select objects from supplied queryable
            from secureObject in source
            // Get user matching current principal id
            join u in this.Users on new { key = userName } equals new { key = u.Name }
            // Get action entry for supplied action
            join ac in this.SecureActions on new { key1 = actionType, key2 = true } equals new { key1 = ac.Type, key2 = ac.AppliesToObject }
```